# Animating an image to create rain effect

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I’m trying to write a simple enough animation with javascript using HTML5 canvas. It’s an image of rain drops that I want to animate seamlessly. This is the image:

https://s31.postimg.org/475z12nyj/raindrops.png

This is how I'm currently animating it:

```
function Background() {
        this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.w = bg.width, this.h = bg.height;
        this.render = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, this.y++);
            if (this.y <= -199) { //If image moves out of canvas, reset position to 0
                this.y = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I’m facing two issues though.

- I can’t get the image to loop at all. It just falls down the one time, I need to have this on a loop so it’ll continue again when it starts to leave the canvas.
- Once I know how to properly loop it, there is the issue that the  rain isn’t suppose to fall down exactly vertically. It needs to  fall down diagonally as the raindrops in the image suggest.

This is where it stops to be a simple enough animation.

Here’s my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qafqyLsy/), it includes all my code. Thanks a lot.

PS: I’ll take any help with either Javascript or CSS I can get. But I do need the rain effect to be using the image only! I can’t accept anything else unfortunately.

Comment: `this.y` starts at `0`, and is increasing`this.y++`, but you wait till it becomes `<0`; even `this.y <= -199`. You'll have to wait quite some time for that to happen ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend splitting out your loop into an animation loop that calls update() and draw() separately. Update your state in update() and then render that state in draw().

Something like this (bit ragged, but you can perhaps make it better :) ):

```js
var lastTick = 0;
var position = { x:0, y:0 };
var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function update(gameTime) {
 position.x += (70 * gameTime.diff / 1000);
 position.y += (110 * gameTime.diff / 1000);
 if (position.x > canvas.width) {
  position.x = 0;
 }

 if (position.y > canvas.height) {
  position.y = 0;
 }
}

function draw(gameTime) {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.drawImage(bg, position.x, position.y, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.drawImage(bg, position.x - canvas.width, position.y, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.drawImage(bg, position.x, position.y - canvas.height, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.drawImage(bg, position.x - canvas.width, position.y - canvas.height, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function loop(tick) {
 var diff = tick - lastTick;
 var gameTime = { tick:tick, diff:diff };
 update(gameTime);
 draw(gameTime);
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 lastTick = tick;
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<title>Rain</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
 canvas {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
 }
</style>
<img id="bg" src="https://s31.postimg.org/475z12nyj/raindrops.png" style="display:none;">
<canvas id="canvas"><h1>Canvas not supported</h1></canvas>
```

Comment: How would you implement your code into mine? Could you update the fiddle with it? https://jsfiddle.net/qafqyLsy/ 
I don't know which bits to paste and which not to.

Comment: All I've done is to update the value of x to give you some diagonal type motion. And then added a call to requestAnimationFrame, so that the render function will loop. Better still would be to create your loop outside of this. And in your loop simply call update(), draw() and requestAnimationFrame(nameOfYourAnimationLoop). Then, in your update() function, you can update the state of your Background object. And in draw, you can call the render() method of your Background object (without the requestAnimationFrame above, of course).

Comment: Okay, thank you, I appreciate the help. But concerning the diagonal motion pointer, using your update of my code still doesn't do anything with the motion of the rain other than just fall down in a vertical fashion. Are you sure you couldn't update my fiddle with how it works for you because I don't think I'm doing it wrong? Sorry for persisting.

Comment: That's ok. I've updated my answer with a full example showing you how to do it, with runnable code snippet :)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Awesome. You could also have multiple drawings of your image overlapped at different speeds, to produce a more rain like effect, but this is simple and looks good enough. Good luck with the rest of it!